# Processing camera frustum() and perspective() rotations

Tags: camera, rotation, center, processing, frustum

How can I make a camera that I can move around and rotate around its own axis in processing 2+?

I have a camera that I can move around in the world space and have some kind of rotation:

```
frustum(-10,10,-10,10,10,2000);
translate(camX,camY,camZ);//I move around by adding to these values when a button is pressed
rotate(angleX,1,0,0);//same here...
rotate(angleY,0,1,0);
rotate(angleZ,0,0,1);
```

Bu the problem with this is that the rotation is centered in the scene, meaning that I get very strange rotations when moving further away from the scene's center coordinates. Why does that happen when I have translated before rotating?

Comment: Are you trying to learn the movement and rotation principles in 3D or are you trying to implement it for something else? For implementation, take a look at PeasyCam for Processing. Also for the sake of learning, you can check out their source code.

Comment: Well, I would like to know the basics for 3d camera movement. Though as far as what I have seen on the web I do not completely understand it.

Comment: What I understand about translation and moving objects in 3d space is not working as expected in this example and I'd really like to know why so I can understand it better.

Comment: I'll be straight with you. Understanding rotation and translation in 3D is a b****. I recently created a 3D scene but unfortunately I can't share much from it or about it. However, this guy's videos and his code in C++ that he provides with them helped a lot: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLW3Zl3wyJwWOpdhYedlD-yCB7WQoHf-My

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Nicolás Carlo and his suggestion to watch [This Youtube playlist](http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLW3Zl3wyJwWOpdhYedlD-yCB7WQoHf-My) made by Jorge Rodriguez I was able to fix what I almost made right the first time.

All I had to do was really just to do some simple trigonometric calculations to get the forward-vector from the angles I got, and then just add the camera position to that for the centerX,centerY,centerZ values in camera();

Ex. where camPos is the current position 3D-Vector and vecForward is the calculated 3D-forward vector that I needed.

```
vecForward.x = cos(yaw)*cos(pitch);
vecForward.y = sin(pitch);
vecForward.z = sin(yaw)*cos(pitch);

camera(camPos.x,camPos.y,camPos.z, camPos.x+vecForward.x,camPos.y+vecForward.y,camPos.z+vecForward.z, 0,1,0);
```

If some of you do not know, Pitch is the up-down angle and Yaw is left-right angle of the camera.

And as a last note here,I highly suggest watching Rodriguez "Math for game developers" that Carlo suggested since every video explains at least one of the most important/oftenly used mathematical solutions at a time to different problems and then giving an example in the end.